# Is it possible to run Py.Test tests on Eclipse Che/Codenvy?

Tags: python, pytest, codenvy, eclipse-che

Self explanatory question here.
Is this even possible? Can't find any documentation regarding this anywhere.. 
And if not, how complicated is it to write a plugin?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

pytest is not currently in the test framework like JUnit is but since you have a command line you could run your tests manually or create a custom command from the commands tab on the left.

1. click the "+" under "TEST"
2. replace the "Command Line" entry that reads `echo "hello"` with 
   `python ${current.project.relpath}`
3. click save
4. With your python test file selected in the `Project Explorer`, click run on your new custom test `shift+F10`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, there's no built in UI to run python tests. However, you may use command line approach.